# Browser default global $ function

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I've noticed that there appears to be a global function called $ in some browsers which is NOT jQuery, but I can't seem to find any [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) on it. What is it?

Firefox: 
[image: Firefox]

Chrome: 
[image: Chrome]

Comment: `$` is just variable that some lib uses. It's not necessary jQuery, any lib can define it.

Comment: The two screenshots were taken from the console on an empty new tab.

Comment: Chrome seems to provide jQuery-like selector but it's only command line API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox dev tools include some useful shortcuts/helpers to manipulate the DOM within the console.

These shortcuts are pretty similar for both: `$` for DOM selection, `$0`-`$4` for "last X selections" and more.

For full reference see:

- Chrome Dev Tools Command Line API - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference
- Firefox Web Console Helpers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers

Comment: Other browser have the same or similar shorcuts (i.e. Safari) but I could not find the link for the official documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **global** `$` in browsers.

Some browsers provide a `$` in the scope of the Console (if there isn't a global one already).

For example [Chrome's documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference) says:

> $(selector) returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. This function is an alias for the document.querySelector() function.